# Account At/With A Bank

Tags: prepositions

Suppose it is a banking situation:

1. He has an account ***at*** a bank.
2. He has an account ***with*** a bank.

Should "*at*" or "*with*" be used?  Is one of them wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In school I learnt that "account **at** a bank" is American English
      and "account **with** a bank" is British English.

They have the same meaning and are both correct.

Comment: This does seem to be [borne out by the NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=account+at+a+bank%3Aeng_us_2012%2Caccount+at+a+bank%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Caccount+with+a+bank%3Aeng_us_2012%2Caccount+with+a+bank%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3), although you can find substantial usage of both phrases in both US and GB corpora.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Ngram ([here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=account%20at%20a%20bank%2Caccount%20with%20a%20bank&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccount%20at%20a%20bank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccount%20with%20a%20bank%3B%2Cc0)) shows that they are used about equally. If there is any difference, 'at the bank' might mean 'physically', as in 'I keep my jewellery at the bank', but an account is not kept physically 'at' the bank.

Comment: My documents are *with* the bank - physically!

Answer (score 1):

As SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher said in the answer with an Ngram, it's clear that both the phrases are used equally and convey the same meaning without creating any complexity. **None of them is wrong.**

But still, if we want to dig in further, I in my opinion we use *at* to refer the bank as the *place* as in *I'm at bank*, *I forgot my cellphone at the bank* and so on. On the other hand, *with* talks about *being a part of bank*. We often say *My documents are with bank,* *Collaboration with bank,* *Tie up with bank...* and etc.

So, *my account is at X bank* talks about the place, the bank which I may not prefer. *My account is with X bank* shows my account is a part of bank.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but they have different nuances. "With" refers to the company but "at" could refer to either the company or the specific branch. So "He has an account at/with MegaBankCorp" are equivalent but you'd probably say "He has an account at MegaBankCorp on Main Street", rather than using "with" in that case.

Comment: So, "an account ***at*** a bank" is probably wrong, because "*account*" is an abstract thing, but "*at*" refers to a physical location?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's wrong, though "with" would probably be more normal. In the old days, your account would physically be at a particular branch of the bank, of course.

Answer (score 0):

While they are generally used interchangeably, there is one exception that I know of. If a bank employee wants to know if you already have an account, he or she will ask "Do you have an account with us?", and never "Do you have an account at us?" Likewise, you would tell a bank employee, "I would like to open an account with you", and not "I would like to open an account to you."